# Distinct query in Hive

Tags: join, hive, distinct

I have 10 tables in hive. I'm joining all these 10  tables to form a single table.

I need unique records in the final hive table.
I can achieve this in two ways

1) Do distinct operation on each individual table and join all these tables to form final hive table.

2) I can join all the hive tables and on final hive table I can do distinct operation.

Any suggestion which option will be good performance wise or in both ways the performance will be same.

FYI- We have huge data in tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you have added both tag `oracle` and `sqlserver` ?

Comment: Want to know how the performance will be there in normal RDBMS as well. So that I know how hive queries will be different from RDBMS queries.

Comment: Joining 2 big tables in Hive is feasible. Joining 10 big tables would require Google-sized infrastructure (if your opinion of "big" is indeed "big"). Good luck.

Comment: Do you have duplicated records in the original tables too?

Comment: @kesco we have duplicates in driver table(main table) as well. Driver table is bigger(15million records) than all others. Few of the tables are look up tables.